# Efficient removal of a set of integers from another set

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have a (large) set of integers `S`, and I want to run the following pseudocode:

```
set result = {};
while(S isn't empty)
{
  int i = S.getArbitraryElement();
  result.insert(i);
  set T = elementsToDelete(i);
  S = S \ T; // set difference
}
```

The function `elementsToDelete` is efficient (sublinear in the initial size of `S`) and the size of `T` is small (assume it's constant). `T` may contain integers no longer in `S`.

Is there a way of implementing the above that is faster than O(|S|^2)? I suspect I should be able to get O(|S| k), where k is the time complexity of `elementsToDelete`. I can of course implement the above in a straightforward way using `std::set_difference` but my understanding is that `set_difference` is O(|S|).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `std::set S;`, you can do:

```
for (auto k : elementsToDelete(i)) {
    S.erase(k);
}
```

Of course the lookup for `erase` is `O(log(S.size()))`, not the `O(1)` you're asking for. That can be achieved with `std::unordered_set`, assuming not too many collisions (which is a big assumption in general but very often true in particular).

Despite the name, the `std::set_difference` algorithm doesn't have much to do with `std::set`. It works on anything you can iterate in order. Anyway it's not for in-place modification of a container. Since `T.size()` is small in this case, you really don't want to create a new container each time you remove a batch of elements. In another example where the result set is small enough, it would be more efficient than repeated `erase`.

Answer (score 0):

The set_difference in C++ library has time complexity of `O(|S|)` hence it is not good for your purposes so i advice you to use S.erase() to delete set element in the S in `O(logN)` implemented as BST . Hence your time complexity reduces to `O(NlogN)`